# Sending xls via API with Java apache poi and React

Tags: java, reactjs, apache-poi

I'm trying to send a **xls** file from my java spring server to react client.

Using default Apache POI constructors creates **xlsx** file, that's not good. In order to override it I have to create the file using FileOutputStream.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("file.xls");
```

But I cannot sent the file over the web. I've tried using the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765335/10319765 I quote: "While downloading a file , your code needs to stream a file chunk by chunk - thats what Java streams are for."

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(inputStreamWrapper.getByteCount())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
        .cacheControl(CacheControl.noCache())
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file.xls")
        .body(new InputStreamResource(inputStreamWrapper.getByteArrayInputStream()));
```

so my controller is sending `InputStreamResource`.

How can I construct `InputStreamResource` using my `FileOutputStream`?

P.S this is my React client:

```
 axios.get('/issues/export', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(response => {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            const blob = new Blob([response.payload.data], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
            saveAs(blob);
        }
    });
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331201/10319765

#### Edit:

I've managed to do that with a trick, right after I've written to the FileOutputStream I've opened a FileInputStream and returned the value.

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("file.xls");
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
    final InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.xls");
    return fileInputStream;
```

but now, the xls file returned as **response to the client** is corrupted and has weird characters inside:
[image]

[image]

The excel file should look the following (taken from my **java server** after sending it):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Eventually what I did in order to solve the corrupted xls file is to work with byte arrays. the controller looks exactly the same but now the return type is `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`. To convert the `InputStream` to byte array I've used `IOUtils.toByteArray()` method.

Client side code has also changed a bit because now the type is no longer `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` but `'blob'`.

```
 axios.get('/issues/export', { responseType: 'blob' }).then(response => {
    if (response && !response.error) {
        const blob = new Blob([response.payload.data]);
        saveAs(blob);
    }
});
```

That's all.